# My java application does not read my files (maven project)

Tags: java, eclipse, file, maven

I have an application in a Java simple project. However, I need to paste this project to a Maven project. So, I basically made a simple Maven project, and I copied and pasted all my classes into it. I need a war to run in a server, and I need to run a Main like a Java application, because this application configures the war application. However, when I run Main, I get some errors that I wasn't having before:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

when in the code is:

```
input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");
```

This didn't work either:

```
faceDetector = new CascadeClassifierDetector("D:/retinoblastoma/workspace/Resources/CascadeClassifiers/FaceDetection/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try not to reference resources and instead try using something like `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`.  Depending on how you have maven setup, these files may have been included within the resulting Jar file.  Which you might like to crack open (with any zip program) and check.  From my (limited understanding), `resources` is included within the class path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a "simple maven project", the maven way is for there to be a `src/main/resources` folder. Did you configure your pom.xml to do something different than that?

If you've done the jar creation portion correctly, the right way to get a file that's **on the classpath** is:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/resource.ext");
```

**The leading forward slash is important!**

If the file is NOT on your classpath (in other words, this will be the case if the above doesn't work), you probably need to configure maven to use a different resources directory.

You do that [like this](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) (change the arguments as appropriate):

```xml
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <targetPath>META-INF/plexus</targetPath>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/plexus</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>configuration.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
    ...
  </testResources>
  ...
</build>
```

Then, your file will be on your classpath and the above code will work. Read the linked documentation above for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this help me to use properties. I realised that my error was another thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a simple Mavne project, all the resources should be located in src/main/resources.You can get the properties file then by (for a non-static method) :

`Properties prop = new Properties();`
`prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));`

For a static method, use :
    `<Class name>.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");`

Refer this link for more information :
[Reading properties file](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html)