# FileNotFoundException while reading an existing file in Java Maven project

Tags: java, maven, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read an existing file in a Maven project, but it shows `FileNotFoundException`. I believe I got the path of the file correctly, and I'm stuck don't know where to go next.
Here is what I have:

- pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>weather</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>weather</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

My Maven Directory Tree:

[image: My Maven Directory Tree]

- I check the path:

```
    String fileName = "/weatherstack.json";
    
    String path = getClass().getResource(fileName).getPath();
    
    System.out.println(path);
```

Output: /Users/.../.../weather/target/classes/weatherstack.json

- Read file:

`Reader reader = new FileReader(path);`

Error: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried going directly to the JSON file in your directory and copying the file location?

Comment: Have you tried `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)`?

Comment: @AdrianRusso Hi Adrian! I tried to "copy path" from the JSON file and it appeared to be the same as the output that I got above. Do you have any idea what could go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @f1sh Hi f1sh! Thank you for commenting. When I try `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)`, it returns null :(

Comment: What if you remove the leading `/` from `fileName`?

Comment: Just a note: `<maven.compiler.[source|target]>` can be replaced by `<maven.compiler.release>` with Java 9+.

Comment: @GeroldBroser thanks for the note. Btw, if I remove the leading `/` from `fileName`, `getClass().getResource(fileName)` will returns `null` :(. I read someone mentioned on another post that the `/` is important to get a file that's on the classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466993/my-java-application-does-not-read-my-files-maven-project

Comment: Please supply minimized but complete classes/methods, not just snippets. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`public FileReader​(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) means that you have to:

- `try...catch` the FNFE inside the method or
- declare it in the enclosing method's header.

Such it is no longer "Unhandled".

Comment: Hi Gerold! Thanks for the answer and I'm sorry for my unclear question. You were right that I should try to catch the exception. The real issue I wanna solve is that I have a valid file and I wanna read it without any exception occured.

Comment: @AugustVo Please edit your Q to make it clear. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I updated my Q. Hope it's clearer now. Thanks for being patient :)

Comment: Hi Gerold! THANK YOU!!! The problem is resolved. It was my bad that I didn't understand your answer correctly. So the case is I need to catch FNFE no matter if the code will throw the exception or not. I understand what it means by "Unhandled" now. After I put the `new FileReader` in `try` and `catch(FileNotFoundException e) ...`, the code no longer shows any error and I'm able to read the file normally. Forgive my stupidity and thanks again! I sincerely appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileReader` constructor that you are calling specifies that `Creates a new FileReader, given the name of the file to read from` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader-java.lang.String-). This is a bit confusing, but it looks like it accepts a file name, and not a file path. You should try using the other constructor like:

```java
Reader reader = new FileReader(new File(path));
```

Comment: Hi Pieter! Thank you for the suggestion. So I tried your way, but it still throws the FileNotFoundException. I checked "File file = new File(path); System.out.println(file.exists());" as well and it returns true. The documentation said "FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading." I wonder if you have any other idea?

Answer (score -1):

In the given image weatherstack.json file is showing in the resources directory and in the target file, it's showing in the classes directory. Delete your target directory and rebuild your project.

Comment: This is Maven's normal processing: "[_**resources:resources** copies the resources for the main source code to the main output directory._](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)". Deleting the `target` directory (not file!) is not going to help in any way.